# scala-meta: type mismatch when unquoting; found: Option[scala.meta.Type.Arg] required: scala.meta.Type

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scalameta

I am playing a bit with the new-style [macro annotations](http://scalameta.org/tutorial/#Part4-Macroannotations) of [scala-meta](https://github.com/scalameta/scalameta). So I extended the example of the @Main annotation:

SConsumer.scala:

```
import scala.meta._


class SConsumer extends scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation {

  inline def apply(defn: Any): Any = meta {
    defn match {
      case q"case class $name($param: $tpe) { ..$stats }" =>
        val accept = q"def accept($param: $tpe): Unit = { ..$stats }"
        q"case class $name extends SConsumerProperty[${tpe}] { $accept }"
      case _ =>
        abort("error!")
    }
  }
}
```

SConsumerProperty.scala:

```
trait SConsumerProperty[T] {
  def accept(param: T): Unit
}
```

It gives the following compiler error:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading project definition from /home/erik/Entwicklung/IntelliJ/Android/Apps/scalandroid/project
[info] Set current project to scalandroid (in build file:/home/erik/Entwicklung/IntelliJ/Android/Apps/scalandroid/)
[info] Packaging /home/erik/Entwicklung/IntelliJ/Android/Apps/scalandroid/target/scala-2.11/scalandroid_2.11-0.0.23-sources.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Wrote /home/erik/Entwicklung/IntelliJ/Android/Apps/scalandroid/target/scala-2.11/scalandroid_2.11-0.0.23.pom
[info] Compiling 4 Scala sources to /home/erik/Entwicklung/IntelliJ/Android/Apps/scalandroid/target/android/intermediates/classes...
[error] /home/erik/Entwicklung/IntelliJ/Android/Apps/scalandroid/src/main/scala/com/bertderbecker/scalandroid/event/SConsumer.scala:14: type mismatch when unquoting;
[error]  found   : Option[scala.meta.Type.Arg]
[error]  required: scala.meta.Type
[error]         q"case class $name extends com.bertderbecker.scalandroid.event.SConsumerProperty[${tpe}] { $accept }"
[error]                                                                                        
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 6 s, completed 17.02.2017 16:16:02
Process finished with exit code 1
```

So, how to convert a Type.Arg into a Type?

Comment: You ever figure this out?

Comment: Yes, after a long research I found `[${Type.Name.apply(the.get.toString)}]`. I'm not sure if this is the 'clean way', but it works for me.

Comment: That workaround is OK if you assume for example that `the` has no type parameters (`x: List[Int]`), is not by-name  (`x: => T`) or repeated (`x: T*`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been bitten by this myself. In general for cases like this, it's good to consult the [`Tree` sources](https://github.com/scalameta/scalameta/blob/28d0bd1acabb4ca2f55eb5a8ff0af03cd3168bcd/scalameta/trees/shared/src/main/scala/scala/meta/Trees.scala#L145-L148).
All `Type` are `Type.Arg` (see `trait Type extends X with Type.Arg` but two `Type.Arg` are not `Type`: `Type.Arg.ByName` and `Type.Arg.Repeated`.

For example,

```
q"def foo(k: Int, a: => Int, b: String*)".structure
res22: String = """
Decl.Def(Nil, Term.Name("foo"), Nil,
         Seq(Seq(Term.Param(Nil, Term.Name("k"), Some(Type.Name("Int")), None),
                 Term.Param(Nil, Term.Name("a"), Some(Type.Arg.ByName(Type.Name("Int"))), None),
                 Term.Param(Nil, Term.Name("b"), Some(Type.Arg.Repeated(Type.Name("String"))), None))),
         Type.Name("Unit"))
"""
```

We can create a helper utility to convert a `Type.Arg` to a `Type`

```
def toType(arg: Type.Arg): Type = arg match {
  case Type.Arg.Repeated(tpe) => tpe
  case Type.Arg.ByName(tpe) => tpe
  case tpe: Type => tpe
}
```

Comment: I've opened a ticket to add this helper to the `contrib` module, see https://github.com/scalameta/scalameta/issues/801